# Putting a gap between columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a webpage that should have 3 columns with whitespace between them.

Here's how it should look:

[image: How it should look]

Here's how it actually looks:

[image: How it actually looks]

How can I fix my code so that the webpage has the gaps between the columns?

I would like a 3 column design that is responsive (and covers all webpage wide when below than 600px wide screen). I don't want 3 absolute measured columns.

Note that I have 1 pixel at the end of the third div: that's intentional, since that's how it looks when viewed with a browser.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="squares"></div>
   <div class="squares"></div>
   <div class="squares"></div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
}

.squares {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is already build with bootstrap, but still here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/m3e6ecLk/).

CSS:

```
#container{
  width: 960px;
}

.squares{
  width: calc(98% / 3);
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 250px;
  float:left;
  background: red;
}

.squares:last-child{
  margin-right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: I still get a white gap between the last div and the end of the container :( it's like 12 px wide.

Comment: Change the width to: 
  width: calc(98% / 3);

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to your Square.

```
.squares{
width: 33.33%;
height: 250px;
background: red;
margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since your divs are touching that you're using a framework that has border-box. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b20n6rvt/):

```
.squares{
  width: 33.33%;  
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.squares div {
    background: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Basically what you did was right. The issue is that the grid needs padding and an interior object. Always use padding for grids, not margins, so the math is much easier. It is much easier to write 33% with whatever padding you want vs. 30% with 3% margin-right. Imagine if you decided to change the margin and you would have to do the math again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create two new classes called first and last.

Add the class first to the first div and the class last to the last div.

Apply a general left and right padding to the divs and give them a box-sizing of border-box

Then remove the padding using the classes first and last.

Here is the jsfiddle of it all in play: http://jsfiddle.net/b20n6rvt/4/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="squares first">
    <div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="squares">
    <div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="squares last">
    <div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
  width: 960px;
}

.squares{
  width: 33.33%;  
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.squares div {
  background: red;
}

.first { 
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.last { 
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```css
.squares {
     width: 33.3333%;
     display-:inline-block;
     float;left
      }
.squares + .squares {
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

The create your red color block inside it
That square will act as grid.

Or you can replace padding by margin, but then you will need to have equal width squares where width of all squares + margin = width of parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve this:

1) Using `display: table`:

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  display: table;
}
.squares {
  width: 33%;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: solid 25px #fff;
}
.squares:nth-child(3) {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
</div>
```

2) Using floats:

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
}
.squares {
  width: 29%;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  margin: 3%;
  float: left;
}
.squares:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.squares:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are well on your way. What you really want is to have these squares being containers as well. Then they can be a third width including padding, which will become your "gap", usually called *gutters*.

This might be a bit of an overkill, but it's a simple guide to the basics of a *grid system*. (This technique is used by [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), though that's a tad more advanced.)

There are a couple of steps to make this *grid system* work.

1. Use the invaluable `* { box-sixing: border-box; }` to make a box model where **padding and borders are included** in your elements width and height.
2. Make a `container/wrapper` which will hold your content.
3. Use `.row` to hold your `.column`. The `.row` should have 100% width + your gutter witdh / 2 as negative margins. (They will be next to eachother.)
4. [Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) your floats.

[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmyRare/31q71bj7/3/)